# Does the @ reply in comments work cold?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, stack-exchange, comment-replies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

I'm curious as to whether the @ reply system in comments works "cold"?  By "cold", I mean by writing someone else's name than is in the question/post...

Say that Oreo asked a question about flipping burgers, and PeanutButter answered.  I knew that Watermelon has expertise in the area of Flipping Burgers, *could I post a comment to Oreo's post with an @Watermelon comment, and would it notify Watermelon* (to come check out this question and lend his expertise)?

**Disclaimer**: Oreo, PeanutButter, and Watermelon are fictitious users on the Stack Exchange Network, no names were changed to protect privacy, or are any users implied or referred to by these names.

> Related: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trust [that FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) that you referenced, hence: no.

> 1. Notifications apply to the author, commenters, and editors of the question or answer that you are commenting on.

Comment: @Arjan: thanks, I did check out that FAQ, but could not find the answer...

Comment: @studio, the FAQ is community wiki, so if the above needs clarification then go ahead! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, done, see the FAQ edit history, and let me know if that works...will upvote you tonight when i get more votes :P

Comment: Ooops, @studio, didn't just create a circular reference, endless recursion, stack overflow...? (By the way: I don't care about the votes.)

Comment: @Studio, perfect now! :-)

Comment: @arjan: actually, it looks like Roger Pate (the original asker of the comments FAQ fixed it...